# How to use VBScript Sub-Classes or set sub-class type properties through a sub or constructor?

Tags: vbscript, subclass

As VBScript doesn't support inheritance, can get/set values for sub-classed parameters:

```
    <%


        Set ChartDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim ChartData: Set ChartData = new ChartDataClass
        With ChartData
            .Essential = 10
            .Lifestyle = 40
            .Spending  = 30
            ' .Average is calcualted
            .ColorScheme("Default")             ' sets chart colors
        End With
        ChartDict.Add "Chart1", ChartData       ' add chartData object to dictionary


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'from using ChartData.ColorScheme("Default"), I want to use ChartData.ChartColors.{OuterLeft, OuterFill, OuterRight, etc...}

    '***************************************************************************** 
    '
    ' Description:
    ' An ASP class to
    '   - create a charts class that contains all required parameters
    '   - for use with essential, lifestyle and spending gauge data sets
    '
    '***************************************************************************** 

    Class ChartDataClass
        Public Essential
        Public Lifestyle
        Public Spending
        Dim ChartColors

        ' automatically calculates the average of the three main values
        Public Property Get Average
            Average = Round((Essential + Lifestyle + Spending) / 3, 2)
        End Property

        ' setting colors
        Public Sub ColorScheme(ByVal SchemeName)
            Set ChartColors = New ChartColorsClass

            Select Case SchemeName
                Case LCase("default")
                    With ChartColors
                        .OuterLeft = ""
                        .OuterFill = ""
                        .OuterRight = ""
                        .OuterRight = ""
                        .InnerLeft = "#3180B8"
                        .InnerFill = "#DADADA"
                    End With
        End Select

        Response.Write("<br>SchemeName: " + SchemeName)
        Response.Write("<br>ChartColors.InnerLeft: " + ChartColors.InnerLeft)
    End Sub

End Class

'***************************************************************************** 
'
' Description:
' An ASP class to
'   - contain color parameters
'   - for use with essential, lifestyle and spending gauge data sets
'
'***************************************************************************** 

Class ChartColorsClass
    Public OuterLeft
    Public OuterFill
    Public OuterRight 
    Public InnerLeft
    Public InnerFill
End Class

%>
```

I would like to set the color scheme with `ChartData.ColorScheme("Default")`, I want to use the set values `ChartData.ChartColors.{OuterLeft, OuterFill, OuterRight, etc...}`

I could just set longer name properties:

`Public ColorOuterLeft, ColorOuterFill, ColorOuterRight, ColorInnerLeft, ColorInnerFill`.

Other options?

Comment: `Public ChartColors`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using public properties to get around this.

Other suggestions though, would be great.

```
Class ChartDataClass
    Public Essential
    Public Lifestyle
    Public Spending
    Public ChartTitle

    Public ColorOuterLeft, ColorOuterFill, ColorOuterRight, ColorInnerLeft, ColorInnerFill

    ' automatically calculates the average of the three main values
    Public Property Get Average
        Average = Round((Essential + Lifestyle + Spending) / 3, 2)
    End Property

        'Constructor
    Public Default Function Init()
        SetColorScheme("default")
        Set Init = Me
    End Function

    Public Sub SetChartTitle(ByVal ThisChartTitle)
        ChartTitle = ThisChartTitle
    End Sub

    ' setting colors
    Public Sub SetColorScheme(ByVal SchemeName)
        Select Case LCase(SchemeName)
            Case "default"
                ColorOuterLeft =  "#BFDFA3"
                ColorOuterFill =  "#d1e8f9"
                ColorOuterRight = "#3b9ac8"
                ColorInnerLeft =  "#3180B8"
                ColorInnerFill =  "#DADADA"
                FontColor      =  "#235E7C"
                FontType       =  "OpenSans"
```